# Convert Korean files that are showing up incorrectly to utf-8 - character shows ÇÑ±¹Ÿî

Tags: encoding, unicode, character-encoding, korean

I was just about to ask this after a long time of searching so decided to answer my own question...

I downloaded Korean subtitles in an .smi file that was in zip archive.  When I extracted it, the Korean characters didn't display properly.  Here is an example line:

.KRCC { Name:ÇÑ±¹Ÿî; lang:ko-KR; SAMIType:CC; }

So I'm wondering how I can decompress this archive to show the correct character encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was that this file was in EUC-KR, and to convert it on linux, simply unzip the archive, and then you can use:

```
iconv -f EUC-KR -t utf-8 -o file.ko.smi file.smi
```